# What is the correct usage of “trailblazer”?

Tags: word-choice, nouns, vocabulary

Let’s say I’ve invented a robot which moves a couple of meters front of me by looking to my direction. It kind of “guesses” where I’m going.

So, if I call it a *trailblazer*, will this be a correct usage?

Is there any better naming for this kind of thing?

Comment: I'd say that name is misleading, because the robot is trying to follow you from the front by predicting your actions rather than setting the direction on its own.

Comment: No. Trailblazer it is not.

Comment: If you are an English-language ***learner***, you might enjoy our sister-site for [ell.se]. That’s because our sister-site is a Q&A site **especially made for *learners***, in contrast to the current English Language and Usage site, which is instead “a Q&A site for **linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts”**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From google,

- a person who makes a new track through wild country.

  - a person who is the first to do something; an innovator.

    *"he was a trailblazer for many ideas that are now standard fare"*

As this robot is chasing (tailing, trailing, pursuing) you, you may choose something on those lines e.g RoboPursuit, ChaserRobo etc, but this totally depends on your choice.

Answer (score 1):

The word "Trailblazer" in this context would infer to someone setting a new course. I think what you are looking for is someone leading you or giving directions.

Answer (score 0):

"Trailblazer" to me would imply "pioneer" who is very active and well informed about "getting to a destination", etc.

Comment: Origin of "trailblazer" may refer to person who made a trail through jungle or other impassable terrain by burning through a path, hence "blazing a trail"

Comment: Actually a blaze is a mark on the trunks of trees along the route, done with paint now but historically often done by hacking off bark.  The blaze is like the white mark on the forehead of an animal, not sure which came first.